# Comparing three range (2 vs 1) and add value (advancefilter)

Tags: vba

I have 2 tables.

One on sheet 1 (f2) and one on sheet 2 (f1).
I've find and adapt the following code to compare value between each table :

```
Sub Complète()
Dim lg&, f1 As Worksheet, f2 As Worksheet
Dim RedRange As Range
Dim i, y, x, z As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set f1 = Sheets("Feuil2")
Set f2 = Sheets("Feuil1")
f1.Activate
lg = Application.Max( _
    f1.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row, _
    f2.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)

Range("r2") = "=COUNTIF(Feuil1!b3:b" & lg & ",b3)=0"

Range("a2:e2" & lg).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("r1:r2"), CopyToRange:=Range("g2:k2"), Unique:=True


Range("g3:j" & [g65000].End(xlUp).Row) _
.Copy Destination:=f2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
```

It's working well but I don't understand how it's work...
My problem is : I would like to add a Range of BAN name which I would like to not copy.

Currently:

1. if a Name is on f2 and is on f1, the name is not copy. (work as expected)
2. if a name is on f1 and is not on f2, the name is copy.

I would like to change de 2nd line to add a new range of name (ExclusionRng) :

3. if the name is in ExclusionRng, then, even if the name is on f1 and is not in f2, it will be not copy. (but do the copy if the name is not in ExclusionRng)

Since I'm beginner with vba, I dont understand why there is a "&" in the dim area for lg.
And the Advancefilter is very fast but I've never work with before...